# How to set up AWS SSO as an Auth0 Enterprise SAML Connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, auth0

I would like to configure AWS SSO as an Enterprise SAML Connection. I tried to cobble together the proper configuration by stealing bits of [Auth0's other SAML IdP examples](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml/identity-providers) but I have not been able to get it working yet.

In AWS SSO:

- configured a new application
- set the **Application ACS URL** to `https://<AUTH0 TENANT>.auth0.com/login/callback`
- set the Application SAML audience to `urn:auth0:<AUTH0 TENANT>:<AUTH0 CONNECTION NAME>`
- download the cert
- assign a user

In Auth0:

- configured an Enterprise SAML Connection
- choose IdP domains
- uploaded the cert, pasted the Sign In and Sign Out URLs from AWS SSO

Currently, clicking “Test” on my Auth0 SAML Connection redirects to AWS SSO, I can log in, but then I get an error “Missing nameId format of subject”.

Has anyone successfully configured AWS SSO as an Auth0 Enterprise SAML Connection?

Just to be clear, I’m ***not*** trying to configure Auth0 as my AWS IdP, so the [Auth0 integrations AWS sso doc](https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws/sso) does not apply

Answer (score 5):

I worked with AWS Support. The answer is:

Add at attribute mapping from Application `Subject` to AWS SSO `${user:subject}` with Format `unspecified`.

Just a note, currently there is no AWS *documented* requirement to map the `Subject` for a Custom SAML application; however, it seems to be required.

Also, currently the global [Attribute Mappings table documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/attributemappingsconcept.html) is hard to find under "Manage Your Identity Source" -> "Connect to Your Microsoft AD Directory" -> "Attribute Mappings" (even though this applies to all application types, not just Microsoft AD).